# Create a subdomain on Namecheap for a Heroku Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, subdomain, namecheap

I have a domain name registered on namecheap. Let's say it is mysite.com. I want this domain to be my personal site. I also want to create a subdomain like myapp.mysite.com for a Rails app on Heroku.

I have tried to configure one in the DNS section of the Namecheap dashboard but I'm new with theses things. I'm using a CNAME type, @ for host and automatic for TTL.

I have also added myapp.mysite.com as a custom domain in my Heroku dashboard.

Am I doing this right? Please explain it in detail so I can learn more about DNS.

EDIT:

I have changed my subdomain like this:

1. Type:  CNAME
2. Host:  myapp
3. Value: mysite.om
4. TTL:   Automatic

Since the DNS has updated, I now get a 400 bad request error from Nginx.
Is it because of Heroku? Do I have to add some setting in Heroku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution for my question. So first of all, the correct configuration for the advanced DNS:

1. Type: CNAME
2. Host: myapp
3. Value: myapp.herokuapp.com (without the https protocol)
4. TTL: Automatic

After that, it takes a moment for the DNS to update the subdomain and make it available. During this time, I needed to add my subdomain to my Heroku configuration. It is possible via the dashboard of via terminal.

I did it via terminal with this command:
heroku domains:add myapp.mysite.com

After some time, it finally worked. However, having a custom domain or subdomain disable the default SSL from Heroku.

I mostly learn via this article:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: For step `3 Value: myapp.herokuapp.com (without the https protocol)` you should point to the provided Heroku Value after you run `heroku domains:add`, example of Value would be `whispering-willow-5678.herokudns.com`

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer didn't work for me. But following the docs did.

0. Open terminal
1. `heroku domains:add www.example.com`
2. `host www.example.com`
3. Copy the url that looks like: `whispering-willow-5678.herokudns.com`

   - Note It will always be suffixed by `.herokudns.com`
4. Add a CNAME Record with the host (`www`, in my example).
5. Paste in the url you copied under `Value` (see screenshot below).
6. Click the check mark on Namecheap
7. Profit

Resources

- [Heroku Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-domain-with-a-subdomain)
- [Namecheap Docs](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9737/2208/pointing-a-domain-to-the-heroku-app/)

[image: Heroku DNS]